# Git manual merge issues

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-submodules, git-merge-conflict

So what I want to do is: There is an old branch `foo` with some changes that I want in a new branch. Here's what I did:

I created a new branch `bar` based off of the branch `foo` and wanted to merge changes from the current working branch `baz` into `bar`. Now I did:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b "baz" "origin/baz"
git merge "bar"
```

There were a few conflicts that I have resolved manually and I have now staged these changes but it won't let me stage some submodules, I get:

```
$ git add path/to/submodule/qux
error: unable to index file path/to/submodule/qux
fatal: updating files failed
```

why is this and how do I get these merged, staged & committed? It's okay to just use the latest submodule as they are present in `baz`.

When I do `$ git submodule update --init --recursive`, I get `Skipping unmerged submodule path/to/submodule/qux` and when I cd there, the direcory is empty...

Comment: Submodules are individual repositories. Go into the submodule and do it there, respectively.

Comment: @dan1st Thank you for your feedback, I updated my original question accordingly

Comment: @LeGEC yes, perfect! That answered it! You can add it as an answer and I will accept, I had to simply do `git reset HEAD path/to/submodule/qux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run reset :

```
git reset HEAD path/to/submodule/qux
```

You can then choose whichever version suits you for this submodule